# Entity Framework 6: Multicolumn unique index featuring navigation property

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-6

How can I set multicolumn index on model like that:

```
public class Meta
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Index("MetaPeriodDateUnq", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    [Required] 
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Index("MetaPeriodDateUnq", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    [Required] 
    public virtual PeriodType Period { get; set; }

    /*
    ...
    */
}

public class PeriodType
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /*
    ...
    */
}
```

After DB initialization there is only "MetaPeriodDateUnq" index mentioning Meta.Date column, but I'm relying on Meta.Date + Meta.Period.Id uniqueness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must include the foreign key explicitly, annotations on navigation properties do generally not work.

```
[Index("MetaPeriodDateUnq", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

[Index("MetaPeriodDateUnq", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
public Guid PeriodId { get; set; }

public virtual PeriodType Period { get; set; }
```

This should work (not tested).

Comment: If you want to keep the default EF naming the Guid PeriodId would be Named `Periods_PeriodId`.